# combining dataframes that have the same 'country name' and same 'year'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I m trying to merge these dataframes in a way that the final data frame would have matched the country year gdp from first dataframe with its corresponding values from second data frame.

[[image: dataframe 1: df_GDP]]
[[image: dataframe 2:df_biofuel_prod]]

first data frame :

| Country | Country code | year | rgdpe |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| country1 | Code1 | year1 | rgdpe1 |
| country1 | Code1 | yearn | rgdpen |
| country2 | Code2 | year1 | rgdpe1' |

second dataframe :

| countries | value | year |
| --- | --- | --- |
| country1 | value1 | year1 |
| country1 | valuen | yearn |
| country2 | Code2 | year1 |

combined dataframe:
| Country | Country code | year |rgdpe  |value|
|:--------|:------------:|:----:|:-----:|:---:|
|country1 | Code1        | year1|rgdpe1 |value|
|country1 | Code1        | yearn|rgdpen |Value|
|country2 | Code2        | year1|rgdpe1'|Value|

```
    combined=pd.merge(left=df_biofuel_prod, right=df_GDP[['rgdpe']], left_on='Value', right_on='country', how='right')
    combined.to_csv('../../combined_test.csv')
```

the results of this code gives me just the rgdpe column while the other column are empty.
What would be the most efficient way to merge and match these dataframes ?

Comment: Please provide dataset in text format. It is difficult to reproduce the problem with image. Refer [this formatting help guide](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#tables)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, from the data screen cap, it looks like the "country" column in your first dataset "df_GDP" is set as index. Reset it using "reset_index()". Then merge on multiple columns like `left_on=["countries","year"]` and `right_on=["country","year"]`. And since you want to retain all records from your main dataframe "df_biofuel_prod", so it should be "left" join:

```py
combined_df = df_biofuel_prod.merge(df_GDP.reset_index(), left_on=["countries","year"], right_on=["country","year"], how="left")
```

Full example with dummy data:

```py
df_GDP = pd.DataFrame(data=[["USA",2001,400],["USA",2002,450],["CAN",2001,150],["CAN",2002,170]], columns=["country","year","rgdpe"]).set_index("country")

df_biofuel_prod = pd.DataFrame(data=[["USA",400,2001],["USA",450,2003],["CAN",150,2001],["CAN",170,2003]], columns=["countries","Value","year"])

combined_df = df_biofuel_prod.merge(df_GDP.reset_index(), left_on=["countries","year"], right_on=["country","year"], how="left")

[Out]:
  countries  Value  year country  rgdpe
0       USA    400  2001     USA  400.0
1       USA    450  2003     NaN    NaN
2       CAN    150  2001     CAN  150.0
3       CAN    170  2003     NaN    NaN
```

You see "NaN" where matching data is not available in "df_GDP".

Comment: thank you for your help, I tried it and got the following error : ValueError: You are trying to merge on object and int64 columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat

Comment: Looks like one of your year column is in non-numeric (possibly string) format. Compare the year columns of both datasets with the output of `df.dtypes`. You can try converting them to numeric by `df_GDP["year"] = df_GDP["year"].apply(pd.to_numeric)` and same for "df_biofuel_prod".

Comment: thanks you a lot, that worked. However I do get the column 'country' and 'countries'. Is there an efficiency way to merge without having it duplicated or do I just have to drop it ?